# Does Highcharts use Cookies?

Tags: highcharts

I am just wondering if Highcharts drops any cookies by default when adding to a page? I am getting 2507 bytes of cookie usage based on my yslow reports. I am not sure where else they could be coming from.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Highcharts do not create any cookies. Cookies are used where data is constant and does not change for long time, while highcharts provide dynamic visual of data on each visit, so it do not save any cookie.

Comment: Thanks! Now have to figure out where those are coming from!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chrome plugins "Attacat Cookie Audit Tool" and "site spider" to find all cookies from defined URL.